# position fixed is not working ? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, layout

```css
#logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 85%;
  left: 40%;
  height: 104px;
  width: 90px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(.9) translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 2px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo::before {
  z-index: 100;
  content: "Brand";
  line-height: 91px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 91px;
  width: 91px;
  left: -8px;
  top: 4px;
  background: black;
}
/*for demo only*/body {height:400px;}
```

```html
<div id="logo"></div>
```

div#logo is not fixed on scroll... why ??
I've written this code on mobile and haven't tried it on desktop yet. So I'm not sure if it's a mobile only issue. I've probably done something silly here

Comment: Perhaps something is overriding your CSS? It seems to be working okay.

Comment: you were correct it was an overriding rule i forgot to remove.. thanks.. you can down vote this now

Comment: Glad it worked out. :) 
Feel free to delete the question if you wish. It's better than being down voted.

Answer (score 1):

I also checked it and it's working fine.
Could you post the whole css and html so We can better look at it? Cheers

Comment: thanks but I've already removed the bug .. it was an overriding rule

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code it all seems to be working fine.

You could try adding `!important` to the position of the logo to see if it works (`position: fixed !important;`). This might work if the CSS is being overridden by another line of code.

If that does not work you need to give us a bit more information about the browser you are using and update the question with the rest of the code. Thanks!